# "d" character in Ext JS template app

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

My environment include Windows 10, Ext JS 6.2.0 (GPL), Sencha CMD 6.5

I created a new Ext JS application by command

```
sencha generate app -ext -classic MyFirstApp .
```

then

```
sencha watch
```

When I see the app in the browser the headings seem to have the character `d` attached:

[image]

This is what the console outputs:

```
GET 
http://localhost:1841/build/development/MyFirstApp/resources/ext-watermark/fonts/ext-watermark.woff [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]
downloadable font: kern: Too large subtable, table discarded (font-family: "Open Sans" style:normal weight:300 stretch:normal src index:0) source: http://localhost:1841/build/development/MyFirstApp/resources/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf  MyFirstApp-all_2.css:6275:12
downloadable font: kern: Too large subtable, table discarded (font-family: "Open Sans" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: http://localhost:1841/build/development/MyFirstApp/resources/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf  MyFirstApp-all_2.css:6289:12
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "ext-watermark" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): status=2147746065 source: http://localhost:1841/build/development/MyFirstApp/resources/ext-watermark/fonts/ext-watermark.woff?n6lnws  MyFirstApp-all_1.css:2797:12
downloadable font: kern: Too large subtable, table discarded (font-family: "Open Sans" style:normal weight:bold stretch:normal src index:0) source: http://localhost:1841/build/development/MyFirstApp/resources/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf  MyFirstApp-all_2.css:6317:12
GET 
http://localhost:1841/build/development/MyFirstApp/resources/ext-watermark/fonts/ext-watermark.ttf [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "ext-watermark" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): status=2147746065 source: http://localhost:1841/build/development/MyFirstApp/resources/ext-watermark/fonts/ext-watermark.ttf?n6lnws  MyFirstApp-all_1.css:2797:1
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**:
I installed Sencha CMD again and created a fresh project. Now it seems to work, but I do not know why.

Comment: Maybe you downloaded the commercial demo of the framework, not the GPL version.

Comment: I downloaded for sure the GPL version

Comment: You can search in project `content: 'd';` and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the font included in sencha causes the error.
You can disable it, and try it with an fresh downloaded font from opensans.com.

To disable it in sencha, use **$enable-font-open-sans: false;** in your sass.

Answer (score 0):

have you downloaded extjs sdk from here https://www.sencha.com/legal/#Sencha_Ext_JS ?

Comment: Yes, I use the GPL version

Comment: ohhh ok it is something related to font files or icon related stuff.